# Unable to create user using Postman - Nodemon App Crashed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

js and in learning phase. I tried to create a new user by saving it into database using mongodb. But when i tried to post the data using POSTMAN, I am getting the following error:

Could not get any response. There was an error connecting to http://localhost:3000/create-user

Nodemon also crashed showing [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I manually run the file and checked but when I tried to post data, connection got lost and terminated.

Below is the server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = require('./models/user');

const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://test:check123@ds211694.mlab.com:11694/parpet',  { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected Successfully');
    }
})
// Middleware for log data
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/create-user', (req, res) => {
    var user = new User();
    user.profile.name = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.save(function (err) {
        console.log('checking.....');
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error');
        } else {
            res.json('Successfully created a new user');
        }
    });
});

const port = process.env.PORT  || 3000;

app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

And the model file is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/* Creating User Schema */
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    password: String,
    profile: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        picture: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    },
    address: String,
    history: [{
        date: Date,
        paid: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        // item: 
    }]
});

/* Hash the password */
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var user = this;
    if(!user.isModified('password')) {
        return next();
    }
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
            if(err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

/* Comparing typed password with that in DB */
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I tried disabling ssl connections as posted in other stackoverflow questions, but this was not helpful.

So can someone please help me to figure it out. It would be really helpful.

```
node --version    = v8.9.3
npm --version     = 6.4.1
nodemon --version = 1.17.5
express --version = 4.16.0
```

Thanks

Comment: Try running without nodemon to see what the console output shows.  Also, you should send a response to create-user even if user.save() fails.

Comment: @JimB. Yeah i tried running without nodemon. When I do the server connection is getting lost and exit from server. Can you please tell how to send response to create-user when user.save fails?

Comment: Difficult to debug without your mongodb connection.

Comment: By any chance are you using any proxy in postman?
You can check that by going to Settings > Proxy
Sometimes I have seen people struggling with this issue.

Comment: @SivcanSingh : Yeah i tried at first, but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this call to bcrypt is quietly crashing:

```
bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
```

I am not sure where the `null` parameter came from.  If you remove it:

```
bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
```

It no longer crashes, and returns no error.

Comment: I tried but it shows the same error Could not get any response in Postman.

Comment: How are you debugging?  Just running at the command line, or using vscode or another ide?

Comment: What was the output in the node console prior to the nodemon app crashed message?

Comment: Debugging from command line.  I am getting this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0

Comment: Looks like malformed JSON coming from the client.  Can you add your client code?

Comment: Actually which one I should select inorder to send data to server in postman? form-data or json in row? I gave form-data with email, password and name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183866/discussion-between-jim-b-and-deepesh-kumar-r).

Comment: Sir thanks a lot you saved my day... Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, got it resolved by downgrading the bcrypt package to 2.0.1.